# c# - is SHORT data type or it is still INT?

Tags: c#, specifications

I am doing some classification and I am not sure:

INT is a primitive datatype with keyword "int"

But I can use Int16,Int32 or Int64 - I know C# has its own names for them. But are those data types as well or it is still INT? And mainly, can we say "short" is a datatype or INT16 is a datatype?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In C#, the following things are always true:

- `short` == `Int16`
- `ushort` == `UInt16`
- `int` == `Int32`
- `uint` == `UInt32`
- `long` == `Int64`
- `ulong` == `UInt64`

Both versions are data types. All of the above are integers of various lengths and signed-ness.

The main difference between the two versions (as far as I know) is what colour they are highlighted as in Visual Studio.

Comment: The color is probably related to whether they are keywords. So you could probably name a variable `Int32`, but not `int`.

Comment: The difference is that the left column contains native C# names, which are preferable. The exception is that calls to static methods and properties of these classes, which should be to the CLR names.

Comment: @Philipp Ah, this is true. I didn't think about that. Not that you should ever name a variable Int32! ;)

Comment: @Philipp: Perhaps you could, but I wouldn't!

Comment: @Steven don't forget, `typeof(int)` is Int32, and it will show up as such in stack traces, etc. So it's still good know.

Comment: all the types in the left columns are just aliases for the types in the right column! The only difference between the usage of these types is syntactical. The types on the left are there to make the programmers lives easier.

Comment: @Philipp: You can still use `int` as a name, you just need to prefix it with @ - for example: `int @int = 0;`. The name is still `int`. I wouldn't recommend this though :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you include the class names then you have to include its namespace, System.

if you use the keyword then no namespaces need to be added.

Answer (score 3):

`short` is a data type representing 16-bit integers (1 order below `int`, which is 32-bit).

`Int16` is in fact also a data type and is synonymous with `short`. That is,

```
Int16.Parse(someNumber);
```

also returns a `short`, same as:

```
short.Parse(someNumber)
```

Same goes with `Int32` for `int` and `Int64` for `long`.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, `int` is just a shorter way of saying System.Int32.

In .NET, even the primitive data types are actually objects (derived from System.Object).

So an int in C# = an Integer in VB.Net = System.Int32.

there's a chart of all the .NET data types here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7%28VS.71%29.aspx

This is part of the .NET [Common Type System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcx1eb1e%28VS.71%29.aspx) that allows seamless interoperability between .NET languages.

Comment: "In .NET, even the primitive data types are actually object" are you sure about this? I always thought of primitives as not derived from object, and converting from and to object requires boxing and unboxing (which the c# compiler hides from you, but still happens at IL level. The old managed c++ (before c++/CLI) made it explicit using __box and __unbox or something similar)

Comment: @Ben: That's Java.  In .NET, value types may be *stored* unboxed, but they still logically derive from `System.Object`, so they can always be used where an `Object` is required. And, yes, this does mean they get automatically boxed, with the boxed version being explicitly derived from `Object`.

Comment: I think you are both right. Behind the scenes, int is generally a 4-byte piece of memory, but logically it's a struct derived from object, and the necessary automatic boxing happens to maintain that appearance. So really, whether or not it's an object depends on the conceptual level you are talking about.

Comment: So I checked Richter's CLR via C# and I think what's happening is: all value types derive from System.ValueType and System.ValueType itself derives from System.Object. So saying that all primitives are objects is indeed correct! ValueTypes are allocated on the stack. Boxing  allocates the necessary memory on the heap plus two additional fields (type object pointer and sync block index) required by objects on the heap and then copies the ValueType into the newly allocated heap memory. Boxing does not happen automatically, but the c# compiler inserts the IL code required for boxing automatically

Comment: ...so it's all objects, but objects on the stack behave different than objects on the heap. So the difference is not in "things that derive from object" versus "things that do not derive from object" but "stack" versus "heap". IIRC c++/CLI allows putting arbitrary  objects (i.e. not objects not derived from ValueType) on the stack.

Comment: Wow... This is a lot of discussion on a point that's covered in almost every intro to .Net book and article I've ever read, not to mention, it's covered in the official documentation, which I linked to initially. (Click on the link to the Common Type system in my answer, and then follow the first link.  It points here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hf02550%28VS.71%29.aspx  where it clearly describes everything you're talking about and backs up my short answer.